# Why the div is not moving leftwards using "right" ? in third step

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Here, I have code a program that revolves the targeted div in a rectangular path using CSS positions properties in `setInterval()` method.

Firstly, the div indeed moves rightwards (using `left` CSS property) and then downwards (using `top` CSS property) but when the thirds step comes it doesn't move leftwards (using CSS `right` property). Why is that so?

```js
let a = 0;
let node = document.querySelector(".node");

let inter1 = setInterval(function() {
  if (a == 260) {
    clearInterval(inter1);
    a = 0;

    let inter2 = setInterval(function() {
      if (a == 639) {
        clearInterval(inter2);
        a = 260;

        let inter3 = setInterval(function() {
          if (a == 0) {
            clearInterval(inter3);
          } else {
            a -= 1;
            node.style.right = a + "px";
          }
        }, 1)
      } else {
        a += 1;
        node.style.top = a + "px";
      }
    }, 1)
  } else {
    a += 1;
    node.style.left = a + "px";
  }
}, 1)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: serif;
}

body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100vw;
}

.node {
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="node"></div>
```

Comment: Moving it left or right should be done using either `style.left` or `style.right` for both . Else you are changing the size unless you clear one of it. So change `node.style.right = a + "px";` to `node.style.left = a + "px";`

Answer (score 0):

Like the user @JavaScript wrote, you should decide for one - left or right.

Therefor you could change `right` to `left` in the `inter3` statement:

```js
let inter3 = setInterval(function() {
  if (a == 0) {
    clearInterval(inter3);
  } else {
    a -= 1;
    node.style.left = a + "px";
  }
}, 1);
```

```js
let a = 0;
let node = document.querySelector(".node");

let inter1 = setInterval(function() {
  if (a == 260) {
    clearInterval(inter1);
    a = 0;

    let inter2 = setInterval(function() {
      if (a == 639) {
        clearInterval(inter2);
        a = 260;

        let inter3 = setInterval(function() {
          if (a == 0) {
            clearInterval(inter3);
          } else {
            a -= 1;
            node.style.left = a + "px";
          }
        }, 1)
      } else {
        a += 1;
        node.style.top = a + "px";
      }
    }, 1)
  } else {
    a += 1;
    node.style.left = a + "px";
  }
}, 1)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: serif;
}

body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100vw;
}

.node {
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="node"></div>
```

Comment: *but when the thirds step comes it doesn't move leftwards* The last movement should be to the left. So only changing `node.style.right = a + "px";` to `node.style.left = a + "px"` from the original code would suffice.

Comment: Ah ok. I updated my answer. Please give a feedback...